# XML/XSL - The value of attribute "test" associated with an element type "xsl:when" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm working on an XML project for school and I can't figure out for the get rid of this error:

[Xerces-J 2.9.1] Checking "portfolio.xsl" for Well-formedness ...
Ln 119 Col 40 - The value of attribute "test" associated with an element type "xsl:when" must not contain the '<' character.
1 Error

```
<xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test= "current<open">
                   <h2 class="up">
                       <img src="up.png" alt="up">
                       <xsl:value-of select="current"/>
                   </h2>
                   <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="current>open">
                   <h2 class="down">
                       <img src="down.png" alt="down">
                       <xsl:value-of select="current"/>
                   </h2>
                   <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
               </xsl:when>
               <xsl:when test="current==open">
                   <h2 class="same">
                       <img src="same.png" alt="same">
                       <xsl:value-of select="current"/>
                   </h2>
                   <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
               </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
```

Any help would be great appreciated it!`

Comment: Escape `<` as `&lt;`.  See [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)

Comment: Note that  `<xsl:when test="current==open">` will also throw an error. It should be (assuming XSLT 1.0) `<xsl:when test="current=open">` or - in your example, preferably `<xsl:otherwise>`.